# AngularJS Service does not parse incoming Json Response to Model in pipe

Tags: angular, typescript, angular17

I am learning AngularJs 17 and created a login application.
However, the response of the server is not getting mapped to the object of the Model Class.

Response:

```json
    {
    "id": 1,
    "userName": "admin",
    "email": "admin@gmail.com",
    "password": "",
    "role": 1,
    "token": "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ1c2VybmFtZSI6ImFkbWluIiwiaWF0IjoxNzA1NzQwMTkzLCJleHAiOjE3MDU3NDE5OTN9.obH83er-eb0Pcl_OLXhwPj7kXUy9lNh0EK3NInr3Eas"
}
```

Model:

```
export class LoginViewModel {
    UserName: string;
    Password: string;
    constructor(){
        this.UserName = "";
        this.Password = "";
    }
}
```

Service:

```
public Login(loginViewModel: LoginViewModel): Observable<LoginViewModel> {
return this.httpClient.post<LoginViewModel>(this.NODE_HOST + "/api/authenticate",loginViewModel,{responseType: "json"}).pipe(
  map(user =>{
    if(user) {
      var userData = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(user));
      this.currentUser = user.UserName;
      console.log("userData-UserName: ", userData.userName);
      console.log("User: ", JSON.stringify(user));
      sessionStorage.setItem('currentUser', JSON.stringify(user));
    }
    return user;
  })
);
```

}

In the service, I am able to hack it using `stringify` and then `parsing` the same to get the  userData in json structure and then I might be able to init a new userObj with that structure but it seems like a dirty way.

In Udemy course, the instructure using angular 11 was able to get the data automatically into ModelClass and in mine (angular 17) its not happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the case is wrong, in your API its `username` in your interface its `UserName`, could you fix that, maybe it will work!

I do not think you need the third argument for `post` first the url and then the post body, will be enough!

Angular will automatically convert the API response to an object, there is no need for `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify((user))`

interface <- please change this if the request also has `userName` instead of `UserName` else its not needed

```
export class LoginViewModel {
    userName: string;
    password: string;
    constructor(){
        this.userName = "";
        this.password = "";
    }
}
```

service

```
public Login(loginViewModel: LoginViewModel): Observable<LoginViewModel> {
return this.httpClient.post<LoginViewModel>(this.NODE_HOST + "/api/authenticate", loginViewModel).pipe(
  map(user =>{
    if(user) {
      const userData = user; // <- changed here
      this.currentUser = user.userName; // <- changed here
      console.log("userData-UserName: ", userData.userName);
      console.log("User: ", JSON.stringify(user));
      sessionStorage.setItem('currentUser', JSON.stringify(user));
    }
    return user;
  })
);
```